# How can I define MakeBoxes for Inactive forms of user-defined heads?

Tags: output-formatting, boxes, hold

Here I define a `MakeBoxes` for `Times`:

```
MakeBoxes[p : Inactive[Times][args___], form_] := 
   MakeBoxes[Interpretation[HoldForm@myHead[args], p], form]
```

And it works as expected:

```
Inactivate[Times[3, 5, 2, 3]]
```

> [image]

But when I define it for my own head `myTimes`,

```
MakeBoxes[p : Inactive[myTimes][args___], form_] := 
   MakeBoxes[Interpretation[HoldForm@myHead[args], p], form]
```

it doesn't work:

```
Inactivate[myTimes[3, 5, 2, 3]]
```

> [image]

Two questions:

1. Why doesn't it work for user-defined symbols:
2. What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: What is `FullForm` of `Inactivate[myTimes[3, 5, 2, 3]]`? I don't have version 10 installed but it seems to me that `Inactivate` must behave differently when operating on different functions.

Comment: Also there is a problematic infinite recursion over `p` when making boxes for this `MakeBoxes` rule (as when one writes `Information[MakeBoxes]`). Recursion is not necessary in this case since you can just use `MakeBoxes[p : Inactive[Times][args___], form_] := With[{boxes = MakeBoxes[HoldForm@myHead[args], form]}, InterpretationBox[boxes, p]]`, i.e. produce the `InterpretationBox` directly.

Comment: @OleksandrR. the `FullForm` of `Inactivate[myTimes[3, 5, 2, 3]]` is `Inactive[myTimes][3, 5, 2, 3]`, so I would have expected `MakeBoxes` to work.

Comment: You could "protect" `myTimes` from being caught by "catch-all" `Inactive` format-value, by using ``BoxForm`UsesPreInPostFixOperatorQ[myTimes] = True``, then your `MakeBoxes` definition for `myTimes` would work. But since `UsesPreInPostFixOperatorQ` has `HoldAllComplete` attribute, up-value on `myTimes` changing `UsesPreInPostFixOperatorQ` doesn't work, and redefining undocumented function seems more evil than changing `FormatValues[Inactive]`.

Comment: @jkuczm well, maybe since it not a `Protected` function, it is meant to be modified as needed?  It would be nice to know what ``BoxForm`UsesPreInPostFixOperatorQ`` really does.  It yields `True` for things with special notation like `Dot`, `Plus`, `NonCommutativeMultiply`, and `False` for most other symbols.

Comment: @QuantumDot it's undocumented so I'd guess it's meant not to be used directly nor modified. There are many "internal" functions that are not protected yet definitely not meant to be modified. As to what it does, its name is pretty telling, it should return `True` when given symbol has prefix, infix, or postfix operator form, but since it's undocumented we can't really be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reorder the way definitions of `Inactive` are applied once you've defined your custom one. By default it was put at the bottom, so the "catch-all" rule is being attempted first.

```
Unprotect[Inactive];

Inactive /: MakeBoxes[p : Inactive[myTimes][args___], form_] := 
  MakeBoxes[Interpretation[HoldForm@myHead[args], p], form]

FormatValues[Inactive] = RotateRight[FormatValues[Inactive]];

Inactive[myTimes][1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> myHead[1, 2, 3]
> ```

Comment: That's interesting... I probably wouldn't have figured that out.  Couple Qs: Is it important to have the rule associated to `Inactive` rather than to `MakeBoxes` directly?  Will user-defined rules *always* go to the bottom (meaning I should use `RotateRight` after every definition)?

Comment: @QuantumDot If you don't use the `TagSetDelayed`, the definition will be associated with `MakeBoxes` and to me it makes more sense to overload `Inactive`. This way if you make tons of overloaded `MakeBoxes` definitions, the definitions are spread out amongst many Heads, rather than one Head having tons of definitions. Makes things more clean IMO.

Comment: @QuantumDot and as far as I know, Mathematica tries to order (top level) definitions from least general to most general. It's usually good about doing this, but in general it can mess up (because how does one generically define which definition is more general?). I think this is just one of those cases. (At least from my experience, I think that's what's going on.)